# Keep local rotation same in the world space

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a mesh which is a child of an `Object3D`, which is a child of the scene.

The `Object3D` is rotated, let's say 90 degrees along X axis.

The child has no rotation applied,and keeps Y -up and Z forward orientation in its local space.

Being a noob to THREE.js API, my question is: What is the most efficient way (in terms of caclulation) to keep the child's rotation aligned with the world's Y?

That is, if its parent has been rotated 90 degs along X  axis,then the local rotation of its child should be updated so that its up vector still points towards global Y axis?

Can I get world's quaternion of the object to get the difference between local and global rotation and then adjust locally?

Well,the easiest trick I found is to inverse parent's quaternion and apply it to the child,so that its local rotation stays the same in the world space:

```
        var inv = mesh.parent.quaternion.clone(); 
        inv.conjugate();
        mesh.quaternion.copy(inv);
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? What were the results? No sense in us offering solutions you've already eliminated.

Comment: @TheJim01 see my update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want your child mesh to remain right-side-up and aligned with the coordinate axes -- even if the mesh's parent is rotated.

There are several ways to do that. What is best, depends on your use case, or personal preference.

Your proposed solution can be implemented without cloning like so:

```
mesh.quaternion.copy( mesh.parent.quaternion ).conjugate();
```

Another approach is to define an `onBeforeRender()` method that modifies the world matrix of the mesh:

```
var func = function() {

    var v = new THREE.Vector3();

    return function func() {

        v.setFromMatrixPosition( this.matrixWorld );
        this.matrixWorld.makeTranslation( v.x, v.y, v.z );

        // or you could do this, instead
        //this.quaternion.copy( this.parent.quaternion ).conjugate();
        //this.updateMatrixWorld();

    };

}();

mesh.onBeforeRender = func;
```

three.js r.94

Comment: That's a clever way of removing the rotation components while salvaging the translation (though you'd lose scale too, if that was important).

Comment: I am sorry,maybe the API namings are confusing but how the translation keeps its rotation the same? Unless you mean not to parenting the child to the rotated object?

Comment: `makeTranslation()` sets the rotation component to the identity, which is what you want.